# Can't install MailParse on cpanel server

Tags: php, email

I've got a linux vps running CentOs 5.5 (cpanel/whm), I've installed MailParse via **Module Installers** section on whm, and it did install it, the end of setup log:

```
running: make INSTALL_ROOT="/root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mailparse-2.1.5" install
Installing shared extensions:     /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mailparse-2.1.5/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/
running: find "/root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mailparse-2.1.5" | xargs ls -dils
508718   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Feb  6 21:08 /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mailparse-2.1.5
508745   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Feb  6 21:08 /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mailparse-2.1.5/usr
508746   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Feb  6 21:08 /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mailparse-2.1.5/usr/lib
508747   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Feb  6 21:08 /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mailparse-2.1.5/usr/lib/php
508748   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Feb  6 21:08 /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mailparse-2.1.5/usr/lib/php/extensions
508749   4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Feb  6 21:08 /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mailparse-2.1.5/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
508744 196 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 193502 Feb  6 21:08 /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mailparse-2.1.5/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mailparse.so

Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mailparse.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mailparse-2.1.5
Extension mailparse enabled in php.ini
The mailparse.so object is not in /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
```

Now, when i try to use mailparse functions using php i get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mailparse.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mailparse.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug in install script. "mailparse.so" is in "/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/", but php looking for it in "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/".

fix "extension=....mailparse.so" to "extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mailparse.so" or "extension=mailparse.so"(if extesion_dir correct) in php.ini.

Run "find /usr/local/lib/ -type f -name "*.ini" -exec grep mailparse {} \; -print" to find php configuration file.

After edit php configuration file, restart Apache from cPanel or "service httpd restart".

Comment: @alvosu Thanks so much, where the specific php.ini is located or should i just create a new one in public html?

Comment: @Tom run command(use ssh root account): "find /etc/ -type f -exec grep mailparse {} \; -print" to find php configuration file

Comment: @alvosu it doesn't print anything

Comment: "find /etc/ -name php.ini -print"

Comment: same, but anyways i've added `extension = "/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mailparse.so"` to `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`, it appeared in phpinfo() that mailparse is active, but now when i try to use it, i get `PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in /usr/local/lib/php.ini on line 789` which is : `url_rewriter.tags = a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset=`.. Any ideas?

Comment: Still the same, the 789 line refers to the last line i've mentioned.

Comment: correct url_rewriter.tags(quoted values): url_rewriter.tags = "a=href...."